# How to declare cluster in java?

Tags: java, collections

I need to create clusters that contain elements. The clusters should be created at run-time and elements to be added to it. How do I do it in Java?

I thought of declaring a class as a cluster, but then I cant declare objects dynamically and iterate over them.

Comment: what is a cluster? Does this have some particular definition?

Comment: A Cluster is some-what similar to a Set. It is dynamically created when needed. The size of each cluster increases dynamically as n when elements are added to it. Like, when I declare Vector v = new Vector(5,10), then initially 5 spaces r created to add element to it, but wen it overflows the vector is extended by 10.
Likewise I need vector of vectors, which can eventually form cluster.

Comment: that still doesn't explain what a cluster is.

Answer (score 1):

You really haven't explained what a cluster is, but you can add "elements" to a `List`. Or indeed anything else in the `Collections` library. Instantiate when you feel like it:

```
List<YourObject> cluster = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
```

and add additional elements when you want, the list will grow automatically:

```
cluster.add(yourObject);
```

You can also iterate over a list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand the question, but you might want to look at the Collections framework.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html